# Add "Formality" parameter to Google NL API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, machine-translation, google-cloud-nl

Is it possible to force the delivery of a more or less formal response via parameter for Google NL or the AutoML models?
Other MTEs [have this functionality](https://www.deepl.com/en/docs-api/translating-text/) but we've not been able to find anything similar while working with the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Google Translate API, like most machine translation APIs, does not support parameters for formality or gender.

You could try to achieve it with an AutoML custom model or with the glossary feature.